# Symfony3 Fos Rest Bundle - download pdf but return json on error

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, fosrestbundle

i have a problem with Fos Rest Bundle - everything works fine with jsons (response is always in this format, including errors). Now i'm stuck with PDF download. I have two problems:

1. I have to send Accept header with "application/pdf" to get pdf file, if i use other type, i'll get an error, that it can't be serialized to json.

   `Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Your data could not be encoded because it contains invalid UTF8 characters."`

   I want to force the endpoint to always use pdf format, no matter what is in the Accept header.
2. When there's an error while generating PDF, the response should be in json format, with error details (it works for other endpoints). Right now, errors are returned in html format.

Keep in mind, that i'm using dev environment for now, so i.e. exception part in config.yml is commented out.

My routing:

- /doc is nelmio api doc - works fine
- /pdf/{id} should accept json and return pdf (with one exception - json on error) - not working as i want
- / (other endpoints) should accept json, and returns json (errors too) - works fine

What i have right now:

1. config.yml

   ```
   fos_rest:
       access_denied_listener:
           html: true
           twig: true
       body_converter:
           enabled: true
       view:
           default_engine: json
           view_response_listener: force
           templating_formats:
               html: true
               twig: false
           mime_types:
               pdf: ['application/pdf']
           formats:
               json: true
               pdf: false
       routing_loader:
           default_format: json
           include_format: false
       format_listener:
           rules:
               - { path: '^/pdf', priorities: ['pdf'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
               # /doc is nelmio api doc, so html is correct here
               - { path: '^/doc', priorities: ['html'], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: false }
               - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
       #exception:
           #codes:
           #    'ApiBundle\Exception\InvalidArgumentException': 400
           #    'ApiBundle\Exception\Exception': true
       serializer:
           serialize_null: true
       service:
           view_handler: api.fos_rest.view_handler
   ```
2. services.yml

   ```
   api.fos_rest.view_handler:
       parent: fos_rest.view_handler.default
       calls:
           - ['registerHandler', ['pdf', ["@api.fos_rest.view_handler.pdf", 'createResponse']]]

   api.fos_rest.view_handler.pdf:
       class: ApiBundle\View\PdfViewHandler
   ```
3. PdfViewHandler.php

   ```
   <?php

   namespace ApiBundle\View;

   use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
   use FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandler;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

   class PdfViewHandler
   {
       public function createResponse(ViewHandler $handler, View $view, Request $request, $format)
       {
           return new Response($view->getData(), 200, $view->getHeaders());
       }
   }
   ```
4. DocumentController.php

   ```
   <?php

   namespace ApiBundle\Controller;

   use ApiBundle\Document\FilledSurvey;
   use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
   use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;

   /**
    * Class DocumentController
    * @package ApiBundle\Controller
    *
    * @Rest\Route("/pdf")
    */
   class DocumentController extends AbstractController
   {
       /**
        * @param FilledSurvey $filledSurvey
        * @return mixed
        *
        * @ApiDoc(
        *   section = "Document",
        *   description = "Get document",
        *   statusCodes = {
        *     200 = "Document returned",
        *   }
        * )
        *
        * @Rest\Get("/{id}", requirements={"id": "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"}, name="document_get")
        * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"???"})
        */
       public function getAction(FilledSurvey $filledSurvey)
       {
           $path = $this->get('api.pdf.generator')->generate($filledSurvey);

           return file_get_contents($path);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: did you find solution ?